# Software design patterns: add a son to a parent, and assign the parent to the son

Tags: java, algorithm, design-patterns

I am working in a tree like structure in which each parent node can contain several sons, and each son can have only one parent, much like a directory structure in a file system.

I have done many of these and have a number of different approach to solve the chicken-and-egg problem than I'm going to share with you now, but I wonder if there is a more of less optimal general design pattern that I've been ignoring so far to solve it.

Now, the issue is that when you set a parent into a son node, the parent must add this new node to its inner offspring list, and when you add a son to a parent, the son must update it's parent, all in order to maintain a coherent tree, otherwise you could end up with parents that have sons that don't recognize them as fathers, and vice versa...

Let's see it with an example (I'll use JAVA), for code problems are better shown in code than explained in paragraphs:

```
class Node {
    private Node parent;
    private ArrayList<Node> sons=new ArrayList<Node>();

    public void setParent(Node parent) {
        this.parent = parent;
        parent.addSon(this);
    }

    public void addSon(Node son) {
        this.sons.add(son);
        son.setParent(this);
    }

}
```

OK, this is the simplest form for the sake of simplicity, although there are other things to deal with (son removal from its previous parent, for example). I'm pretty sure you already see the recursive problem we have here.

An more or less obvious approach is to check at runtime whether the son has already assigned this as its parent, so I'd rewrite those methods as:

```
    public void addSon(Node son) {
        this.sons.add(son);
        if (son.parent != this)
            son.setParent(this);
    }
```

But I wonder if there would be a better approach to solve this. For example, another approach that will save some redundant calls could be using an static method, something like:

```
 class Node {
    private Node parent;
    private ArrayList<Node> sons=new ArrayList<Node>();

    public static assignSon(Node parent, Node son) {
        parent.sons.add(son);
        son.parent = parent;
    }
}
```

So, provided assignSon is the only method one can use to relate sons to their fathers, this solves the chicken-an-egg problem but it is also somehow less intuitive to use from outside, and you'll have to write more code, you know, where before you can do something like:

```
son.setParent(parent);
```

Or

```
parent.addSon(son);
```

You'll to write now:

```
Node.assignSon(parent, son);
```

It's not a big deal, but still... well, whatever. If you know an optimal approach for this problem and you want to share with this community, I for one will be very thankful!

TIA!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I would go with the same code as *@uoyilmaz*, but remember to update the old parent (if already present), otherwise if you are assigning a son already assigned to someone else you will get some inconsistency.

For example if from this tree:

```
   a
 / | \
b  c  d
```

you move `d` as a son of `b`

```
  a
 / \
b   c
|
d
```

`a` will still have the reference to the `d` node.

So maybe something like this should work:

```
class Node {
    private Node parent;
    private ArrayList<Node> sons=new ArrayList<Node>();

    private void setParent(Node parent) {
        this.parent = parent;
    }

    public void addSon(Node son) {
        if(!this.sons.contains(son)) {
            this.sons.add(son);

            if(son.parent != null) {
                son.parent.sons.remove(son);
            }

            son.setParent(this);
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: In your `removeSon` method you have to deal with `son` 's parent. Because you are removing a son from its parent but the `son` isn't aware of that.

Comment: What do you mean? You have to see the `removeSon` from the object perspective, so the method is removing a son from "me" (if exists). This method is called from the parent of the son in the `addSon` method. So what I'm doing is: "ok, I'm adding `d` as a son of `b`" -> `b.addSon(d)` and then "ehy `d`, do you have a parent?" "Yes, it's not null because it's `a`." "Oh, cool, excuse me `a`, could you remove `d` from your sons?" -> `d.parent.removeSon(d)`.

Comment: @Enrichman This looks really good, indeed, but you still have two problems here. First, maybe you didn't dealt with this for simplicity too, but anyway within the addSon method you will have to check first that you don't have that son already in the sons list, otherwise you'll end up again with a son that knows her father, but a father that doesn't recognize its son. And second, being removeSon method public and taking your last tree let's say you call removeSon(b) from outside that class, from that moment 'a' will know nothing about 'b', but 'b' will still "think" that 'a' is his father.

Comment: @Enrichman Nonetheless, the two problems pointed out before have easy solutions I think. Get rid of removeSon method at all and deal directly with the sons property in the addSon method, or make removeSon private if you think it makes the code more clear. And for the first thing, just check if this.sons.contains(son) at the first line of addSon and leave the method in such case. Could you add those changes to see how things go that way? It seems I could edit it by myself, but I find somehow rude to edit other's code without explicit permission... ;)

Comment: @Enrichman Thanks! I think I am going to use this approach. Anyway, I am gonna give it sometime for other coders to add their opinions, if they want, before accepting an answer.

Comment: @Fran yep, good points. Added the suggested edits and removed the removeSon (we can call it directly from the parent.nodes!) :)

Comment: @Fran sure. If you don't need any order you can go also for an HashSet instead of a list, in this way you can avoid the contains check and be safe for any dups.
I like this kind of questions because they help me on HackerRank, lol.

Comment: @Enrichman My point was exactly was Fran repeated. You can't look at this from the object's perspective you need to look at it from the Class perspective. You spotted correctly the issue with uoyilmaz code that wasn't dealing with removal. why didn't you say that's the external code's responsibility to do the removal? I believe that was because you want a coherent class as well. So the same principal applies in here you need to deal with existing parent with you add a son which now you are doing. It's looking pretty good now.

Comment: @Enrichman I think it could be more efficient if you enclose everything in the addSon method within the first if block, because if that condition is not matched, there is no point in running any of the code there (you see, in such case you will remove the son from its parent just to add it again to the same parent).

Answer (score 1):

I think in order to avoid the chicken and egg roblem, you can write an addSon method that call setParent, or vice versa, but not both ways, like below. I consistently use it in trees when I have to implement a way to go up the tree.

```
class Node {
    private Node parent;
    private ArrayList<Node> sons=new ArrayList<Node>();

    private void setParent(Node parent) {
        this.parent = parent;
    }

    public void addSon(Node son) {
        this.sons.add(son);
        son.setParent(this);
    }
}
```

Comment: That's another approach and for sure it breaks the chicken-and-egg problem, but the drawback is that this can left the tree in an non-coherent state very easily. You know, you could end up with a son that has a parent, but which parent doesn't know anything about that son at all.

Comment: Actually, you only call addSon method when adding a node to the tree. You first add son to parent, then register parent to son. I fail to find a scenario that can end up with a parent that doesn't know anything about a son that recognizes it as a parent.

Comment: why doesn't the son know anything about the parent? `this` is the parent given and `this.sons` is the array of sons he has. So he knows about his sons doesn't he? Or am I way too tired already to realize anything here.

Comment: @uolimaz Here is one scenario: You add `son1` to `parent1` and `parent2` in that order. With your current code, both `parent1` and `parent2` think that `son1` is their son but `son1` thinks its parent is `parent2`

Comment: @xetra11 I said it the other way around. I can't write code in the comments properly, but I hope you understand it anyway. If outside this code you do a call to son.setParent(parent) and you forget to call parent.addSon(son) later, the son will never be assigned to the parent's sons list. So in such an scenery the son knows about the parent, because it is in its parent property, but the parent know nothing about the son. Now, I didn't realized setParent was private, what makes something like that unlikely to happen because you are forced to call addSon instead.

Comment: @Fran hm - yea the private makes the deal. Creating a non-child parent would just be a `new Node()`

Comment: @xetra11 I can see that now, but still there is the problem the other way around as pointed out by Amin J Anyway, I think that could be easily solved by just adding a son.parent.sons.remove(son) before the this.sons.add(son)

Comment: You're right, if you need to move the nodes in the tree, you should clean old references, both parent and child, before establishing the new references. I was only thinking about building the tree once. And as you said, you are forced to add child node, the reference to parent is not set explicitly.